# Apache2 rewrite url to chanage url

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, apache2

i have a php project,here is a url like this

```
127.0.0.1:1000/manage/api/info
```

,manage is the root of the project,now i want do this ,when i visit

```
`127.0.0.1:1000/api/info`
```

,I could get the host,just ignore the root manage,how can i do this? 
I have search the stackoverflow but doesn't meet my question,does it can be solved in rewrite?
I thik i should config the apache2.conf,if i open the write modle i may work?
i use ubuntu 14.04 apache2.4.7

Answer (score 0):

You have to set your apache configuration to point to manage folder as your web root. Below is the apache configuration you can add to your vhosts file.

```
<VirtualHost *:1000>
ServerAdmin "webmaster@api.com"
DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/manage"
ServerName local.myapiapp.com
<Directory "/var/www/html/manage">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

Additionaly, you can also add local.myapiapp.com to /etc/hosts file. Then go to browser and put in local.myapiapp.com in the address bar. It will point the root directory i.e. manage.